# How to connect a M24 Multi Pin Connector to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware, dc-motor

How do i connect a M24 Multipin Motor Plug Wire that is coming from a brushless motor to a raspberry Pi , I know i need to use an ESC however the wires attached to my brushless motor is a multipin motor 
Something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32863931162.html)

Comment: your question has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi ...... the only suggestion that I can make is for you to build an adapter

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> How to connect a 24 pin BLDC motor plug to Rpi?

***Answer***

Well, I have been playing with various kinds of BLDC motors, mostly 24V to 30V.  BLDC motors usually have 3 to 5 connecting wires, and many more with speed encoders.

There is no standard colour codes for the red, black, yellow, white, blue wires, so you need to very carefully read the datasheet, to make sure you don't connect the blue wire wrongly to the red wire etc, and white smoke comes out.

Your 24 pin plug should use only 3 to 5 wires to connect to your BLDC motor.  You can check which motor'scolour wire connects to which of the 24 pins.

Of course you can DIY your own plugs to replace the industrial grade heavy duty plug.  I am playing with hobbyist grade motor for RC toys, so I only use Tamiya grade connectors, and I pretty sure they are OK.

> For smaller toys motors I just use 0.254" DuPont connectors for Rpi
>   and so far so good.

***Warning:*** BUT if your motor is huge, then perhaps you can give me the advert/datasheet web link of your motor, just to make sure, or *I might give you a severe warning to stop playing with fire*, ...

You might like to read the following BLDC motor with AB Encoder for reference.

[AliExpress CHR-GM25-370-ABHL BLDC Motor with Encoder 6/12/24VDC - US$10](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/Moteur-Chihai-CHR-GM25-370-ABHL-DC-magn-tique-Holzer-encodeur-motor-ducteur-6-0-V/32842600463.html)

[image: bldc motor 1]

I once used a similar BLDC motor and found it powerful.  You might like to compare its wiring with yours.

[image: bldc motor 2]

***References***

[Driving an ESC/Brushless-Motor Using Raspberry Pi - AGTx, Instructable Circuits 2018](https://www.instructables.com/id/Driving-an-ESCBrushless-Motor-Using-Raspberry-Pi/)

[Brushless DC Electric Motor -Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor)

[AliExpress Brushless DC motor speed controller 12V 24V 36V 48V with Hall sensor 10 / 50DPW15BL bldc motor driver US$36](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/12V-50w-Brushless-DC-Motor-Controller-Forward-Reverse-Soft-start-Brake-Hall-Sensor/32654322273.html?spm=a2g0w.search0104.3.166.3ef224a679pDRN&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_9_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=b5e5de2a-62c6-4d9c-b8f1-9eccc821efca-25&algo_pvid=b5e5de2a-62c6-4d9c-b8f1-9eccc821efca)

[BLDC Motor Driver BLD-300B DC18-50V 15A - ¥160](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.64.102341e81yGobR&id=545286198463&ns=1&abbucket=6#detail)